# Documents required for B2 at airport

Tags: usa, paperwork, b1-b2-visas

I am a resident of India. I have a valid B1/B2 Visa with ten year multiple entry. I want to accompany my wife who is on her Business visit for a month. I intend to travel with her for tourist purpose and come back after 2 weeks, I want to do a trip over to east coast for those 2 weeks. I want to know what documents i need to support at the US Port of Entry.

Please do let me know so that i have a smooth immigration.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need any extra documents other than your valid passport with a valid unexpired visa if you are entering the US on a (B1/B2) visa.

From [immihelp.com](http://www.immihelp.com/travel/united-states-admission-documents.html):

> - **Nonimmigrants**
>
>   - Passport.
>   - ....
>   - Valid, unexpired visa stamp in the passport for the category under which you are applying to enter the U.S.

Anyway, out of personal experience, it will never harm you if you bring extra documents to prove your intentions of the visit, eg. hotel reservation, invitation letter and return tickets.

Comment: I've visited US 3 times on a B1, and the 2 times I visited for > 10 days I was asked for a detailed list of meetings I had scheduled...  the 3rd time they only asked for a company ID

Comment: For a B2 I would carry hotel and return ticket proofs at a minimum...  And maybe bank statements to further strengthen my case

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I went through this a couple of times. Sometimes it can be hard at the border and you can be asked a lot of questions, but as the other answer noted, it can be good to have extra docs.

I had printed info about places I want to see, name of the hostel and a reservation for flight back.

Also, I think your wife will need B2 visa, as well, if she wants to travel to USA, but her company will probably organize this.

Good luck!